# What is the meaning of 'Rajasthan shades off into the fertile land of Gujarat'

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase 'shade off into'?

Is 'off' a preposition here?

Here, Rajasthan and Gujarat are States of India.

Comment: It "gradually changes to" something else ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/es/diccionario/ingles-espanol/shade-off)). I see you're new here--welcome to EL&U! Please do give some time to the [tour]; this question should have included your basic research, which would probably have answered it already. Cheers!

Comment: @Conrado can you explain more, please I couldn't develop understanding in this question.

Comment: @Conrado is suggesting that before asking questions here you might look at online sources. For example, see https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shade-into   After  you have done a little work on the question yourself, there may still be things to ask us about.

Comment: @Anton but please, can you explain figurative meaning of this sentence

Comment: It means that there is no abrupt change in the land as you go from Rajasthan to Gujarat. The land changes only gradually as you travel from one to the other.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Henry's answer has a link to a good picture/map, showing how the trees or other plants become less and less over a large area, in stead of ending all at once. Cheers!

Comment: @Henry https://english.stackexchange.com/q/554034/398943

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much of Rajasthan is the Thar desert and extremely arid.  If you look at an [aerial view](https://www.google.com/maps/@25.6009937,72.1197317,376064m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en), you will see that the transition to Gujarat in the south is gradual, in contrast to the transition to the Indus valley in the west, which is sudden.

If you were painting or drawing the gradual transition, you might do so with a [shading technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading) with a succession of deeper greens, and that is metaphorically applied here for the physical appearance of the change.